# Using the "combine" document class with the listings package

Tags: listings, combine

I am trying to use the `combine` document class ([manual](http://www.tex.ac.uk/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/combine/combine.pdf)) to combine several pre-existing documents into a single file with consistent formatting. It works great, except that there is a conflict of some kind with the listings pacakge. When I try compiling with `\usepackage{listings}` in my main document file, I get

```
ERROR: LaTeX Error: Command \c@lstlisting already defined.

--- TeX said ---
           Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.
```

This happens even without any usage of the package.

My guess is that the listings package automatically defines some things at each `\begin{document}`, and this is causing the trouble? (I'm really not sure if that is even possible, but that's what it looks like...)

Does anybody have any ideas for a workaround? (For the time being I'll just use `verbatim` environments for my code snippets, but I'd love to have the syntax highlighting etc. provided by listings.)

Edit: Here's a minimal version of a document with the error:

```
\documentclass{combine}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}

\begin{papers}
  \coltoctitle{Title}
  \coltocauthor{Author}
  \label{lbl}
  \import{test}
\end{papers}
\end{document}
```

with another file, `test.tex` in the same directory, which can have anything in it, so long as its valid tex. For my minimal example, I did

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
 Hello world
\end{document}
```

If `\usepackage{listings}` is commented out, it compiles fine. If it is uncommented, it gives the error as shown.

Comment: Can you recreate the error with a [minimal version of your document?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)? Without that it is hard to tell.

Comment: The `\c@lstlisting` macro is the `lstlisting` counter. You could try `\makeatletter\let\c@lstlisting\@undefined\makeatother` short before the line where the error appears to official declare the macro undefined. Also often a `\relax` is used instead of `\@undefined`.

Comment: Alright, I just added a minimal example... I will try `\relax`ing or using `\@undefined` and see what I get. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Lo! adding `\makeatletter\let\c@lstlisting\@undefined\makeatother` just before the `\import{}` command worked! I also tested when including a document that actually uses `listings` -- still works :-) thanks a ton!

Comment: @Martin if you add that as an answer, I'll accept it. It solved my problem. For future reference, it needs to be added before each `\import` -- on my actual document, I was including a number of them, and had to put it before each one, whether the imported document was using `listings` or not.

Comment: @Martin: Please turn your comment into an answer.

Comment: @lockstep: Done. I somehow didn't saw the notification for the last comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `\c@lstlisting` macro is the `lstlisting` counter. You could try `\makeatletter\let\c@lstlisting\@undefined\makeatother` short before the line where the error appears to official declare the macro undefined. Also often a `\relax` is used instead of `\@undefined`.