# How to use the combine document class with the siunitx package

Tags: siunitx, combine

I am trying to squish several journal papers together (using the `combine` document class) to provide the filling for my thesis sandwich.  The papers make use of the `siunitx` package but causes an error.

A similar posting is here: [Using the "combine" document class with the listings package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19494/using-the-combine-document-class-with-the-listings-package) from which I have adapted the folowing minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{combine}                  
\usepackage[load=named]{siunitx}
\begin{document}

\begin{papers}
\coltoctitle{Title}
\coltocauthor{Author}
\label{lbl}
\import{test}
\end{papers}

\end{document}
```

and in test.tex

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
 Hello World
\end{document}
```

and I get the following error:

```
ERROR: LaTeX error: "kernel/command-already-defined"    
--- TeX said --- !
! Control sequence \c_siunitx_textsf_tl already defined.
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: If you simply want to have journal papers like they are in your thesis use the `pdfpages` package. If you want to merge them to build your thesis I would rather do this manually.

Comment: @Martin: I looked at `pdfpages` but wouldn't be able to reference equations and figures in the Discussion and Conclusion as easily, or add the papers' TOCs to the main thesis TOC

Comment: How many papers are we talking here? It seems to me that the manual route is worth it for something as significant as a thesis. In fact, many universities do not allow this (mine did not either). I assume you've checked the guidelines for your school on this though!

Comment: @Mark: Just three papers-in-progress.  If you mean 'does my uni allow a thesis in the paper sandwich format' then Yes it does.  I am not against manual methods in principal but I would have to maintain the main TOC and any \refs I make in the main document that refer to the papers when the papers develop.

Comment: I wound up writing papers and thesis in tandem. It's a surprisingly good way of experimenting with structure. I understand where you're coming from though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say, this is caused by code at the beginning of the document. At least for the minimal example, simply bypassing this code in the subsidiary document works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\@ifclassloaded{combine}
  {\let\@begindocumenthook\@empty}
  {}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
 Hello World
\end{document}
```

(`\@begindocumenthook` is where the `\AtBeginDocumentCode` is stored.)

Comment: Thanks Joseph I was hoping you would chip in!  Works great.  I should correct what I said above about being able to "reference equations and figures" in sub documents from the main document: it can't be done.

Comment: I am combining several documents. I need the siunitx package so I used Joseph's suggestion. Unfortunately, this causes other problems with, for example, section numbering (3.65 instead of 4) and the numbering of theorem like environments. Does anyone know of a way to avoid this problem.