# combine documents of different classes

Tags: input, include, exam, article

I need to add to an article another document, class exam. `include` and `input` don't work properly if the preamble is different. I must add some multiple choice and clozes as an appendix to the article I'm writing before the bibliography. Thanks in advance!

Comment: probably the easiest thing to do in this case is to process the other article to a pdf file, then use `pdfpages` to insert the images.

Comment: yes, I've tried that, but I would also like to keep the page numbers, if possible, as well as have the titles appear in the table of contents.

Comment: `exam` class load `article.cls` so you can start by using `exam` as your document class

Answer (score 2):

You can try the [`combine`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/combine) package/class. An example can be found in [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19494/using-the-combine-document-class-with-the-listings-package).